# I want to know what is system.out.println() doing in this code

Tags: java

I don't know why there are system.out.println in the end of these code. what  is this and why is it here?

This code is a code from my friend, he told me to understand this code and I don't understand why there are system.out.println after this code.

```
public class Nestedlooplab2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (byte i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (byte j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            for (byte k=1; k<=(5-i);k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } System.out.println();}
    }
    }
```

Comment: `println` prints a new line (at the end of what ever it was printing, but since it's not actually printing anything, it just puts new line into the output stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's take a look at the output of your code:

```
.****
..***
...**
....*
.....
```

As a String, this is the same as:

```
.****\n..***\n...**\n....*\n.....\n
```

Using `System.out` in Java writes to the standard output-stream of characters by default. When you write to this stream, you can use various methods, including `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`. Calling `print` will output the *exact* String that you provide to it, whereas calling `println` will output the String you provide to it, followed by a new line (the [line separator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) for your system). If you call `System.out.println()` (`println` with no parameter), you will output the String you provided (`""`) as well as move the output to the next line. Essentially, this means removing calls to `System.out.println()` in your code will result in the following output:

```
.****..***...**....*.....
```

This output will look exactly the same as a String. As you can see, there are no newline characters (`\n`) within your output when you only call `System.out.print` and don't call `System.out.println`.

Finally, let's take a look at your code in the context of making it easier to read and understand. I'm using the Java 11+ feature [`String.repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) to massively simplify the operation of repeating a String here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(".".repeat(i)+"*".repeat(5-i));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.****
..***
...**
....*
.....
```

This is equivalent to the original output. However, it's *much* clearer to read and understand what is going on. Supposing that you don't have access to those features, you can do the following instead:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for(int rpts = 0; rpts < i; rpts++) {
    System.out.print('.');
  }
  for(int rpts = i; rpts < 5; rpts++) {
    System.out.print('*');
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

This snippet of code also has the same output. Its content is not much different from your code snippet, as your code snippet *does* have the right idea. However, it is more consistently formatted, which makes it easier for yourself and others to read the code. Do note how the repeats are labelled with a name `rpts`, and (in both examples) the iteration variables are ints. Java programmers usually use ints to iterate because the space you save from using `bytes` to iterate is negligible enough to ignore for most applications, and integers cover most ranges of values you might want to iterate over.

Comment: P.S. You should also look up `System.out.println` and `System.out.print` yourself. I'm 100% certain there are helpful explanations out there already.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!

By itself a `System.out.println()` will just print a newline character, e.g. `\n`. If you were to add a parameter to this statement it would print your parameter along with a newline.

[Here are the JavaDocs for `println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--)

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

The code you linked would print a certain amount of `.` characters and certain amount of `*` characters without any line breaks. The final `System.out.println();` would then print a newline character and the loop would start over again.

Output:

```
.****
..***
...**
....*
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of your code is:

```
.****
..***
...**
....*
.....
```

Without the `System.out.println();`, the output would be:

```
.****..***...**....*.....
```

The `System.out.println();` prints a new line character to the screen for each interaction of the loop.